# How to center buttons on screen horizontally and vertically plus equidistant apart?

Tags: android, user-interface, layout

I've been racking my brain (android newbie here, so not hard to do) for awhile trying to figure out how to accomplish this:

[image]

using a RelativeLayout or something other than AbsoluteLayout which is what this was created with.  I'm coming from a Windows programming background where the device adjusts the 'absolute' positioning for you and GUI layout was a non-issue.

The first layout works great in the emulator, but doesn't format for my Nexus One or any other screen that differs from the emulator size.  I expected this because it's absolutely positioned, but haven't found a solution that will format correctly for different screen sizes.  My goal is to have the layout work for different screen sizes and in portrait / landscape.

Here's the Code that I'm currently using:  [main.xml]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AbsoluteLayout 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>
  <Button
    android:id="@+id/Button01"
    android:layout_width="188px"
    android:layout_height="100px"
    android:text="A"
    android:layout_y="50px" android:layout_x="65px" android:textSize="48sp"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Button02"
    android:layout_width="188px"
    android:layout_height="100px"
    android:text="B"
    android:layout_y="175px" android:layout_x="65px" android:textSize="48sp"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Button03"
    android:layout_width="188px"
    android:layout_height="100px"
    android:text="C"
    android:layout_y="300px" android:layout_x="65px" android:textSize="48sp"/>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Using tidbits from other questions here, I came up with this, it’s closer, but not there yet.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout
android:gravity="center"
android:id="@+id/widget49"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/Button01"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="A"
    android:textSize="48sp"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Button02"
    android:layout_width="0dip"        
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="B"
    android:textSize="48sp"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Button03"
    android:layout_width="0dip"      
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="C"
    android:textSize="48sp"/>
</TableLayout>
```

Here’s a picture of the TableLayout:

[image]

Any help / guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 24):

Using the recommendations from both of you worked perfectly!

For those interested, here's the final main.xml code in RelativeLayout format that matched what I was trying to do with the AbsoluteLayout..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/Button02"
    android:layout_width="188dip"
    android:layout_height="100dip"
    android:text="B"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:textSize="48sp" android:textStyle="bold" />

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/Button01"
    android:layout_width="188dip"
    android:layout_height="100dip"
    android:text="A"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_above="@id/Button02"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dip"
    android:textSize="48sp" android:textStyle="bold" />

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/Button03"
    android:layout_width="188dip"
    android:layout_height="100dip"
    android:text="C"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/Button02"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dip"
    android:textSize="48sp" android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Also, on an interesting note that may help someone in the future.  When I modified the first code I posted with these recommendations I received this error when trying to compile: "**\res\layout\main.xml:9: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_above' with value '@id/Button02').**

With a little Googling on what could be the cause, I discovered that since the reference to Button02 (via the Button01 code) occurred before Button02 was actually created, this generated the error.  So note in the final code Button02 is declared **FIRST**.

Comment: Thanks for this good example, this made very clear to me about relative layout and +1 for placing button2 above button1 in this example

Answer (score 12):

Use a `RelativeLayout`. Button B has `android:layout_centerInParent="true"`. Button A has `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"`, `android:layout_above="@id/Button02"`, and some `android:layout_marginBottom` to establish whatever whitespace gap you want. Button C has `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"`, `android:layout_below="@id/Button02"`, and some `android:layout_marginTop` to establish whatever whitespace gap you want.

Do not use `AbsoluteLayout`, period.

Comment: Also, don't use px (pixels), use dip (display independent pixels).

Comment: Thanks for posting your complete answer, I copy and pasted it into my code and it works great.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a good example using TableLayout.  It has three table rows, each with layout_weight = 1 that ensures each row takes up 1/3 of the screen.  The middle row will contain your buttons and the first and last table rows are empty.

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TableRow android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"/>
    <TableRow android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:gravity="center">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:padding="24dp"
                android:text="Button 1"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:padding="24dp"
                android:text="Button 2"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:padding="24dp"
                android:text="Button 3"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </TableRow>
    <TableRow android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"/>
</TableLayout>
```

**Edit...**

And this is another similar way that allows the button width to match the parent.

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TableRow android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:padding="24dp"
        android:text="Button 1"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:padding="24dp"
        android:text="Button 2"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:padding="24dp"
        android:text="Button 3"/>
    <TableRow android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"/>
</TableLayout>
```